# Вредит ли неоригинальное зарядное устройство аккумулятору ноутбука?

Tags: ноутбук

есть ноутбук lenovo на нижней крышке указаны параметры входящего тока 20В 3.25 А  65 ватт. ноутбук приобретался с рук. поэтому зарядное устройство было не оригинальное. "APD" 19В на 3.42 А. 65ватт.
знаю что с мобильными телефонами есть такое, что неоригинальная зарядка  быстрее приводит  к изнашиванию аккумулятора, но по ноутбукам не удалось найти информацию, так ли это,  лучше ли купить именно оригинальное зарядное от компании леново 3.25 на 20 . или текущее зарядное не будет хуже в плане сохранения аккумулятора? Уточнение сама зарядка идет нормально.ноутбук lenovo ideapad 15ITL05

Comment: Вреда не будет. Новое устройство менее мощное, ресурс батареи чуть-чуть возрастет. Учтите что батарея старится и сама по себе если вы её используете (заряжаете/разряжаете). Я бы не беспокоился из-за зарядки.

Comment: ошибся. не 2.42 а 19В на 3.42 А. 65ватт.

Comment: Тогда вся разница в пределах погрешности. Не беспокойтесь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ноутбуку ничего не будет, как уже написал Станислав. А вот числа с блока питания ("зарядки") мне не очень нравятся. 19В х 2.42 А = 46 <<< 65 ватт. Как минимум, батарея будет заряжаться медленнее, и есть риск поврежедения самого БП. Убедитесь, что он не нагревается очень сильно в самом напряжённом режиме - работа ноутбука одновременно с зарядкой аккумулятора. Если вы обнаружите сильный нагрев, то блок питания лучше заменить на более мощный.

Выход из строя блока питания, когда он подключён к ноутбуку, может повредить и ноутбук.

Comment: ошибся. 19 на 3.42 . 65 ватт

Comment: Ну, тогда должно быть всё хорошо.

Comment: @Kromster медленнее - значит медленнее. Мене мощный БП даёт меньший ток, значит нужно больше времени, чтобы батарея набрала заряд. А у вас какие мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: БП же отдаёт столько мощности, сколько умеет, почему вдруг он должен перегреться (т.е. отдать больше мощности, чем та, на которую он рассчитан)? Насколько я понимаю, ноут может попросить от БП режим помощнее, но если зарядка не умеет, она этот режим просто не даст.

Comment: @CrazyElf это если там ноут и  БП с управлением питанием. Скорее всего, да, но не факт. И если БП исправен, то волноваться не о чём. Но мы знаем, что БП левый, и выходное напряжение у него 19 В, а не 20, как должно быть по спецификации управления питанием. Возможно, что БП без управления питанием. В общем, нужно быть начеку.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я не знаю, есть ли в БП с управлением питанием защита от перегрузки. Если вдруг нету, тогда перегрузка вполне возможна - нагрузку помощнее подключи, и всё.

Comment: @CrazyElf правило большого пальца, не эксплуатировать оборудование в предельных режимах продолжительное время. Чем более низкокачественное оборудование, тем больший запас стоит выдерживать.

Comment: @Kromster пусть будет будет, а батарея нам ничего не должна. Я даже исправил. Е!

Comment: Стало лучше, ловите плюс. А свои более неактуальные комметарии я удаляю